# with mvc.net partial view, how do i access the model assigned to the template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I have another simple question for all you mvc gurus.

I have a partial view with the following definition.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<IList<whoozit.Models.PictureModel>>" %>
```

How do I access the data that has been assigned to the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
<% foreach (whoozit.Models.PictureModel picture in Model)
   { %>
    <%: picture.property1 %><br />
    <%: picture.property2 %><br />
    etc...
<% } %>
```

Comment: aha, the keyword is Model.  Thanks.